# adding json dependency to a library module in android studio

Tags: android, json, gradle

I created a new library module to my project in Android Studio. A class in this new module accesses `org.json.JSONObject`.

I'm getting the error:

> failed to resolve org.json:json:20141113

when trying to build the project.

Here's how my build.gradle file looks:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile project(':app')
   compile files('libs/volley.jar')
   compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is the correct path  --> compile 'org.json:json:20141113'

Comment: Yeah, same as here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20141113

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a repository to your configuration maybe that helps.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

For more information see here:

- [User-guide: Dependency Management Basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Test This one , Worked for me

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.cedarsoftware:json-io:4.10.1'
}
```